# C++: 'adding references' to namespaces (and class libraries)?

Tags: c++, dll, namespaces, reference, visual-studio

I'm curious about adding references through the "Property Pages" dialog in Visual Studio C++.  Specifically adding 'class libraries' and, even more so, 'namespaces'.

In what I'm reading it says that both 'class library's and 'namespaces' can be referenced in this way-- I can see what the reference for 'class libraries' are for (bringing in a dll to be able to access it's '.h' files and such-- correct me if I'm wrong).  But what does referencing a namespace do?  I understand the 'using' declarative allows you to not qualify the namespace anymore-- is this 'referencing namespaces' just another way to do that?

To clarify by what I mean by 'referencing':
I'm talking about when right clicking on a project in the solution explorer and selecting 'References' which then brings up the 'Property Pages' dialog and then finally selecting the 'Add New Reference...' button.

Comment: Is this .Net? 'Class library' sounds like a .Net thing. If not please clarify where these are, I don't see them in my project settings.

Comment: Are you sure you're using C++?

Comment: Yes it's .Net.  'Class Library' just means a .dll file full of classes I believe.  yes, I'm using C++.  I'm talking about when right clicking on a project in the solution explorer and selecting 'References' which then brings up the 'Property Pages' dialog and then finally selecting the 'Add New Reference...' button.

Comment: If it's .NET then it's most likely C++/CLI which not C++. A similar language with the intention of making it easy to write glue code for existing codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Add a reference' in .NET is somewhat like `#include`ing in normal C++. It allows you to use classes and namespaces inside another .cs file, that is not in the project, e.g., system libraries.
If you're coding normal C++, don't worry about it.

Comment: Am I right in the following?  With #include ing, the file/s must be in the same directory as the file that is doing the #include ing.  But with 'Add a Reference' it makes it so you can still utilize the chosen file even when it is in a different location.  Is this the basic difference?

Comment: Bump.  [Will delete when previous comment is answered...]